# How to know the position of items in a Python ordered dictionary

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

Can we know the position of items in Python's ordered dictionary?

For example:

If I have dictionary:

```
// Ordered_dict is OrderedDictionary

Ordered_dict = {"fruit": "banana", "drinks": "water", "animal": "cat"}
```

Now how do I know in which position `cat` belongs to?
Is it possible to get an answer like:

`position (Ordered_dict["animal"]) = 2 ?` or in some other way?

Comment: You dictionary isn't an ordered dict -- it's an unordered plain Python dict.

Comment: Just because you call it ordered dict doesn't make it one!

Comment: I know that this is an old question now, but what the previous 2 commentors are trying to say is that there is a class called OrderedDict in the collections module which you need to use if you want your dict to preserve order.  Its also good to follow the python naming convention where classes are in CamelCase and variables in snake_case, so your variable should be ordered_dict (i.e. no capitalization of the first character).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You may get a list of keys with the `keys` property:

```
In [20]: d=OrderedDict((("fruit", "banana"), ("drinks", 'water'), ("animal", "cat")))

In [21]: d.keys().index('animal')
Out[21]: 2
```

Better performance could be achieved with the use of `iterkeys()` though.

For those using Python 3:

```
>>> list(d.keys()).index('animal')
2
```

Comment: `list(d.keys()).index('animal')` for anyone using **Python3** ending up here.

Comment: It seems that simply using `list(d).index('animal')` also works in Python 3, unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 6):

For Python3: `tuple(d).index('animal')`

This is almost the same as Marein's answer above, but uses an immutable tuple instead of a mutable list. So it should run a little bit faster (~12% faster in my quick sanity check).

Comment: Note that this also works in Python 2 (tuple(d) just iterates over the keys of the dictionary and produces a tuple)