# OrderedDict in python 3 - how to get the keys in order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordereddictionary

In python 2 when using an `OrderedDict` I was able to get the keys in the order they were inserted by simply using the `keys` method that returned a list. In python 3 however:

```
rows = OrderedDict()
rows[0]=[1,2,3]
rows[1]=[1,2,3]
image = [rows[k] for k in rows.keys()[:2]]
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'odict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

I certainly can do `list(rows)[:2]` as advised for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897750/how-to-know-the-position-of-items-in-a-pythons-ordered-dictionary#comment33333583_6897813) - but is this guaranteed to get me the keys in order ? Is this the one right way ?

**UPDATE**: the python 2 code would be better as:

```
image = [v for v in rows.values()[:2]]
```

which of course still blows with the same error on python 3

Comment: Yes, doing `list(rows)` is the correct way to get the keys in order since that uses `__iter__` and `__next__` which are guaranteed to be ordered.  If you only need the first 2 keys, you might want to consider something like `itertools.islice(rows, 2)` instead of `list(rows)[:2]` ...

Comment: Thanks @mgilson - not sure what would be faster - copying a small list or using the itertools module - maybe try an answer ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@mglison is right. Because `OrderedDict` follows the iterator protocol, it is guaranteed to `yield` the keys in the correct order to `list()`:

<s>However, like @mglison also mentioned,`itertools.islice()` would be better and more efficent than simply using `list` and subscripting. After timing both methods multiple times using the `timeit` module, the `itertools` method was roughly 2x faster. Here are the exact numbers:</s>

After getting the average time of running both `list(itertools.islice(rows, 2))` and `list(rows.keys())[:2]`(notice I'm casting the result of `islice()` to a list) multiple times, it appears that using the latter method is actual slightly faster:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  list(itertools.islice(rows, 2))   |    1.5023668839901838  |      
---------------------------------------------------------------
|  list(rows.keys())[:2]             |    1.495460570215706   |      
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, the difference of the two numbers is so small, I really would not make much of difference which method you use. Just choose the method which is the most readable and understandable for your specific case.

Comment: If that's exactly what you did, I don't think it's a fair comparison: `itertools.islice(rows, 2)` by itself doesn't make a list.  You'd need to compare it to `list(itertools.islice(rows, 2))`, and I suspect the two approaches would look a lot closer at that point.

Comment: @DSM Ah, your right good catch. I don't where my brain was. I'll recalculate the code snippets and update my answer.

Comment: zzzz please add the timeit code zzzz :) - @DSM - however I am interested in iterating over the keys in order so that may be a fair comparison

Comment: Thanks - I am off to bed - by the way now that I look carefully I probably need `itertools.islice(rows.values(), 2)`

Comment: I think that whether or not `itertools` will win out is highly dependent on how big the dictionary is.  If the dict is really large, I suspect that itertools will be faster.  If the dict is small, then the performance difference is probably negligible either way.

Comment: @mgilson Yes, your right. My timings were based off of the OP's comment - _"Thanks mgilson - not sure what would be faster - **copying a small list** or using the itertools module - maybe try an answer ? :)"_.

Comment: The behavior on generator being slower than the list constructor is expected - see for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138661/my-list-comprehension-is-faster-than-equivalent-code-with-generator-expression#comment58013879_35138661. Of course if the dict was enormous iterators would win. However timing this is off topic - what we are interested in is _iterating over the list of keys_ so your previous timings were more relevant (please also post the timit code). Also see the update to the question - does what hold for `keys()` hold for `values()` too - I guess yes.

Comment: Btw my comment on _copying a small list_ referred to the `rows.keys()[:2]` copy